# Get forbidden when try query request receipt

Tags: uber-api

I have a app on uber with [request_receipt scope avaiable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzjmW.png)

But when i trying to get a request receipt with a token created in my app i got [Forbidden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enDKf.png) error.

Others endpoints (map, product, history...) are ok.

My authentication request is fine too and return:

```
{
  "expires_in"=>2592000, 
  "token_type"=>"Bearer", 
  "refresh_token"=>"[...]", 
  "last_authenticated"=>0, 
  "scope"=>"history profile history_lite places ride_widgets all_trips request_receipt", 
  "user_id"=>"[...]"
}
```

I made this requests on app and get same error.

Answer (score 1):

You can only access trips that were initiated through your own Uber integration. For instance, if you book a ride through the Uber app and take that request id, you won't be able to access the details of that ride. Here's what the [docs](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/requests-request_id-receipt-get) state:

> The receipt endpoint will only provide receipts for ride requests originating from your application. It is not currently possibly to receive receipt data for all trips.